# rpar error "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments:"

Tags: r, regression, decision-tree, rpart

i am running regression tree using formula 
`model <- rpart(ttl_pl ~ . - var1 - var2 - var3 - var4 - var5 - var6, data = clv_1st, method = "anova", cp = 0.00005, minsplit = 10000, minbucket = round(nrow(clv_1st)*0.01), parms = list(split = "information"), model = TRUE)`

As you see I want to remove several variables, so everything is ok with removing until I try to remove `var6`, which is character, all others variables which I wanted to remove are integers or numeric format. When I try to remove `var6` I get an error `Error in cats[match(names(xlevels), colnames(X))] <- unlist(lapply(xlevels,  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments`. How to solve this issue? I don't want to remove variable from data set, but only from rpart.

Comment: I may be wrong but I guess the error is not because of `var6` it's because of other variable which are either not `numeric` or `factor` i.e. apart from **var1 to var6** there are some fields ***which are character***[either remove those or convert them to factors.]

Comment: No, all variables except ```var6``` are numeric or integer format. And I everything works fine until I add ```var6```, I mean that I do not get error if I use formula withou ```var6``` ```model <- rpart(ttl_pl ~ . - var1 - var2 - var3 - var4 - var5, data = clv_1st, method = "anova", cp = 0.00005, minsplit = 10000, minbucket = round(nrow(clv_1st)*0.01), parms = list(split = "information"), model = TRUE)```